# How to resolve NumberFormatException in Java?

Tags: java, numberformatexception

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {

            BufferedReader red = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String s = red.readLine();
            int t = 0;
            int l = 0;
            int c = 0;
            t = Integer.valueOf(red.readLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
                l = Integer.valueOf(red.readLine());
                c = Integer.valueOf(red.readLine());
                for (int j = 1; j <= l; j++) {
                    for (int k = 1; k <= c; k++) {
                        if (j == 1 || j == l || k == 1 || k == c) {
                            System.out.print("*");
                        } else {
                            System.out.print(".");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            l = 0;
            c = 0;
            t = 0;

            red.close();

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3 1"

I think the input is not proper and thus it is unable to convert to `int` but I am unable to resolve this. Many times, I get an error if I do not use the `try-catch` block.

Comment: As an aside, `Integer.valueOf(String)` returns a new `Integer`. You want to use `Integer.parseInt(String)`.

Comment: We need to see the file you're reading. The problem is the space in the file between the 3 and the 1. Also, which line does this occur on? Because that will help tell you which line in the file has the space.

Comment: Define "resolve". What would you want to happen if the line you read is not a valid integer (and `3 1` is not a valid integer)?

Comment: the given input is of l and c ,separated by a space. I think it is unable to take the readings of l and c as integers due to this space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
l = red.nextInt(); // straight to int
c = red.nextInt(); // ditto
red.nextLine();  // to clear the newline from the buffer
```

If the current line of input is `"3 1"`, `l` will be assigned `3` and `c` `1`.

Note that although this code may work, it is brittle; you probably want to add code to protect against bad data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions like String.split on your inputs lines to cut it according to your separators (white spaces here) :

```
String line = red.readLine();
String[] items = line.split("\\s");
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Another usefull method is String.trim() to remove blanck caracters from the beginning and the end of a String.

```
String line = "  test  ";
line = line.trim(); // "test"
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Another point is that you can write the try/catch block only around the Integer.parseInt() calls, not aroung the full loop :
this way you will have an error based on the line in error and not stop the full process. But this is about your error handling : if the input contains only one "bad caracter" (ie: 'a'), do you want to stop the full process in error or just log a message and continue.